Are the Particular Integral and Complementary Function orthogonal?
I am a physics student so please forgive my lack of rigour.
Suppose I have a Linear, Inhomogenous O.D.E given by Ly(x) = f(x).
I may construct a solution from the Greens function, G(x,z), by integrating the driving function f(x) with G(x,z). My first question is whether this solution is equal to C.F.+P.I. or just P.I. alone? My intuition tells it is just the P.I.
Now suppose I use the Wronskian to construct a second solution from a Particular Integral solution, would my second solution just be the complementary function? Would C.F. and P.I. consequently be orthogonal to each other?
Thank you!

What are C.F. and P.I.?

C.F. Is the Complementary Function and P.I. Is the Particular Integral.
